# CS50 Readability not giving correct grade level

Tags: c, cs50

CS50 Readability Pset2. I have almost finished everything. Everything works except the expected grade level given to the user. After inputting some texts, it gives me the correct grade level, but for some it doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_letters(string text);
int count_words(string text);
int count_sentences(string text);

int main(void)
{
    //ask user for text
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    //calculate number of letters
    int numLetters = count_letters(text);

    //calcuate number of words
    int numWords = count_words(text);

    //calculate number of sentences
    int numSentences = count_sentences(text);

    float L = 100 * (float) numLetters / (float) numWords;
    // printf("L: %0.4f\n", L);
    float S = 100 * (float) numSentences / (float) numWords;
    // printf("S: %0.4f\n", S);

    int grade_level = round(0.0558 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);

    if (grade_level < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }

    else if (grade_level >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }

    else
    {
        grade_level++;
        printf("Grade %i\n", grade_level);
    }
}

int count_letters(string text)
{
    int letters = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            letters++;
        }
    }
    return letters;
}

int count_words(string text)
{
    int words = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i <strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if(isspace(text[i]))
        {
            words++;
        }
    }
    return words;
}

int count_sentences(string text)
{
    int sentences = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?')
        {
            sentences++;
        }
    }
    return sentences;
}
```

Example:

Both of these sentences should give me Grade 8:

> Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, "and what is the use of a book," thought Alice "without pictures or conversation?"

and

> When he was nearly thirteen, my brother Jem got his arm badly broken at the elbow. When it healed, and Jem's fears of never being able to play football were assuaged, he was seldom self-conscious about his injury. His left arm was somewhat shorter than his right; when he stood or walked, the back of his hand was at right angles to his body, his thumb parallel to his thigh.

The first one about Alice returns the correct grade. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to print the variables `numLetters`, `numWords` and `numSentences` and check if these are correct. Then check the calculation. I tried to improve the formatting. Please check if the two input texts are correct as I removed quotes and punctuation. Please [edit] your question and show the wrong result you get. BTW: Did you intentionally use `float` and not `double`?

Comment: " gives me the correct grade level, but for some it doesn't." -->Post the input,  output seen and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and working just fine . You made some mistake in line  `int grade_level = round(0.0558 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);`and the line `grade_level++;` in the else statement is unnecessary.
When I editted these lines the code is giving the derired output. Both the above inputs that you provided are giving `Grade 8` as output. Below is the code you can see I didn't make any other changes, just these two.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_letters(string text);
int count_words(string text);
int count_sentences(string text);

int main(void)
{
    //ask user for text
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    //calculate number of letters
    int numLetters = count_letters(text);

    //calcuate number of words
    int numWords = count_words(text);

    //calculate number of sentences
    int numSentences = count_sentences(text);

    float L = 100 * (float) numLetters / (float) numWords;
    printf("L: %f\n", L);
    float S = 100 * (float) numSentences / (float) numWords;
    printf("S: %f\n", S);

    int grade_level = round((0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8);
    printf("%i\n", grade_level);


    if (grade_level < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }

    else if (grade_level >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }

    else
    {

        printf("Grade %i\n", grade_level);
    }
}

int count_letters(string text)
{
    int letters = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            letters++;
        }
    }
    return letters;
}

int count_words(string text)
{
    int words = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i <strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if(isspace(text[i]))
        {
            words++;
        }
    }
    return words;
}

int count_sentences(string text)
{
    int sentences = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?')
        {
            sentences++;
        }
    }
    return sentences;
}
```